# ADB and Fastboot in Ubuntu on ARM

Tags: arm

Is it possible to get ADB and Fastboot for Android working in Ubuntu running on the ARM Samsung Chromebook under crouton?  I'm having no luck finding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can install ADB and Fastboot.

First update Repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools && sudo apt-get update
```

then install ADB and Fastboot

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

After installation check the ADB connection by

connect device via USB cable

Tpye adb devices and hit enter you will get an id of device connected to system.