# ADB on ARM7 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, arm, adb

Im needing to get ADB version 1.0.32 installed on my Beaglebone black Rev b loaded with Ubuntu 14.04. I have attempted to bring down the latest version of Android from the SVN @ Google and compile it but im coming up short. The furthest ive gotten with that is it giving me compiler errors:

```
ubuntu@arm:~/system/core/adb$ sudo make
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
 g++  -DADB_HOST=1 -DHAVE_FORKEXEC=1 -DHAVE_SYMLINKS -DHAVE_TERMIO_H  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -std=c++11 -I. -I../include  -c -o adb.o adb.cpp
In file included from adb.cpp:19:0:
sysdeps.h: In function ‘char* adb_dirstart(const char*)’:
sysdeps.h:532:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 return strchr(path, '/');
                        ^
sysdeps.h: In function ‘char* adb_dirstop(const char*)’:
sysdeps.h:537:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 return strrchr(path, '/');
                         ^
make: *** [adb.o] Error 1
```

but despite my C# programing knowledge and without a decent IDE to work with this im more or less a stick in the mud on this.

I know i can bring down adb using APT from the repositories but its a version to old to interface with my Android 5 phone.

If anyone is willing to help me figure out the issues with the build, or if anyone has the binary for the latest ADB for the ARM7 platform i would very much appreciate getting a copy of it.

I've been searching Google for the past 48 hours straight trying to find this answer on my own, time to reach out for help :)

Ive gone through this page: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb but it apperantly only links for X86 X64 systems not ARM (took me a few to figure that out)

My make file is from: https://gist.github.com/cstratton/2d3be0682f3c5312a5cd 
[ADB and Fastboot in Ubuntu on ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351382/adb-and-fastboot-in-ubuntu-on-arm?rq=1) only installs 1.0.31

Thanks Guys!!! Im quite sure there are others looking for this as well

Answer (score 1):

I've been there. Helpful resources: https://github.com/bonnyfone/adb-arm with build instructions and base script then modify it following Arch linux to get 1.0.32 (original is for 1.0.31) https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/Makefile?h=packages/android-tools

Result:

```
$ ./adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

Any AOSP release over 5.0 has 1.0.32 so you can set it to what you want, I used branch=android-5.0.1_r1 in the script.